# Has any recent boycott against a media due to fake news channel succeeded?

Tags: media, fake-news

In 2017 Romania was full of [anti-corruption protests](https://time.com/4660860/romania-protests-corruption-problem/) and some media channels have been far from journalism deontology when reporting these protests (example: [dogs paid by Soros to protest](https://www.scmp.com/news/world/europe/article/2084148/dogs-paid-protest-fake-news-flooding-romania-and-fuelling)).

Some proposed an economical boycott against the media channels reporting such news by inviting companies to not finance advertising. However, [this article](https://universul.net/newsweek-boicotarea-antenei-3-nu-a-afectat-veniturile-televiziunii-din-contra-profitul-a-crescut/) shows that virtually all the companies soon came back and displayed ads on those channels.

I am wondering if any such boycott managed to reach its goal:

- more recent than 1990
- income from advertising has significantly lowered for a while (e.g. decrease by 10% or more for more than one year)
- serious lack of journalism deontology as the main cause for the boycott (e.g. fake news)

**Question:** Has any recent boycott against a media due to fake news channel succeeded?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The campaign against Breitbart organised by among others the Twitter account Sleeping Giants may qualify. Breitbart lost approximately [90% of their advertisers](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/business/wp/2017/06/08/breitbart-lost-90-percent-of-its-advertisers-in-two-months-whos-still-there/) over a three month period in 2017 and have not yet recovered. They have also since then lost about [75% of their readership](https://web.archive.org/web/20190704000739/https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/whatever-happened-to-breitbart-the-insurgent-star-of-the-right-is-in-a-long-slow-fade/2019/07/02/c8f501a2-9cde-11e9-85d6-5211733f92c7_story.html). The boycott was explicitly motivated by accusations of spreading fake news and collaborations with white nationalists.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about how Ben Shapiro leaving Breitbart might have been the reason for its decline has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111357/discussion-on-answer-by-johanna-has-any-recent-boycott-against-a-media-due-to-fa).